# How to use Django-filer(asset file manager)?

Tags: python, django, django-filer

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to use Django-filer? I have installed the necessary tools for the filer to work and I get the Filer tab in the admin interface, but when I upload an image to the app I am not able to get the preview thumbimage. The image is also uploaded to the Media_root path(Public files default path). What else have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. I had missed that when `easy_thumbnails` is automatically pulled in by `pip`, you still have to explicitly add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.

I spotted this because when I was uploading images, they weren't appearing in the clipboard, and when inspecting the response from the upload, there was an internal server error complaining that an `easy_thumbnails` table wasn't available.

tl;dr; check you added `easy_thumbnails` to your settings and did a `migration` / `syncdb`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in your urls.py. You should have the following code in it:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('', (
        r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

Cheers